# javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I've the following service method:

```
public List<ClientView> getClientList(boolean isGlobal, Client client, Address address) {            
    List<ClientView> clientList = null;
                
    try{
        Query CQuery;
        String queryForClientList= "SELECT NEW org.domain.carsclass.pojo.ClientView(c.clientId, c.name, c.lastName,c.taxNo, a.mobilePhone, " +
                                   "a.town, a.postCode, a.addressLine1, a.clientAddress.companyId, "+myParam.getCompany().getCompanyId()+" ) FROM Address a INNER JOIN a.client c ";
        System.out.print(queryForClientList);
        System.out.print("Company" + myParam.getCompany().getCompanyId());
        if(isGlobal==false)
        queryForClientList +=      "WHERE a.clientAddress.companyId="+myParam.getCompany().getCompanyId()+" ";
        else {                 
        queryForClientList +=      "WHERE ( a.clientAddress.companyId="+myParam.getCompany().getCompanyId()+" or " +
                                   "NOT EXISTS (SELECT a2.clientAddress.clientId, a2.clientAddress.companyId FROM Address a2 " +
                                   "WHERE a2.client = c AND a2.clientAddress.companyId = "+myParam.getCompany().getCompanyId()+")) ";
        }     
        if(client.getClientId() != null && !client.getClientId().toString().isEmpty())
            queryForClientList +=  "and c.clientId = '"+client.getClientId()+"%' ";
        
        if(client.getName() != null && !client.getName().isEmpty() )
            queryForClientList +=  "and c.name like '"+client.getName()+"%' ";
            
        if(client.getLastName() != null && !client.getLastName().isEmpty())
            queryForClientList +=  "and c.lastName like '"+client.getLastName()+"%' ";
        
        if(client.getTaxNo() != null && !client.getTaxNo().isEmpty())
            queryForClientList +=  "and c.taxNo like '"+client.getTaxNo()+"%' ";
    
        if(address.getMobilePhone() != null && !address.getMobilePhone().isEmpty())
            queryForClientList +=  "and a.mobilePhone like '"+address.getMobilePhone()+"%' ";
        
        if(address.getTown()!= null && !address.getTown().isEmpty())                            
            queryForClientList +=  "and a.town like '"+address.getTown()+"%' ";

        if(address.getPostCode() != null && !address.getPostCode().isEmpty())
            queryForClientList +=  "and a.postCode like '"+address.getPostCode()+"%' "; 
        
        if(address.getAddressLine1()!= null && !address.getAddressLine1().isEmpty())
            queryForClientList +=  "and a.addressLine1 like '"+address.getAddressLine1()+"%' ";
        
        if(isGlobal == false)
            queryForClientList +=  "ORDER BY c.name, c.lastName ASC";
        else                       
            queryForClientList +=  "GROUP BY c.clientId ORDER BY c.clientId DESC";
    
        CQuery = entityManager.createQuery(queryForClientList).setMaxResults(20);
        System.out.print(queryForClientList);
        clientList = (List<ClientView>) CQuery.getResultList();
        System.out.print(queryForClientList);   
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
        
    
        System.out.print("PersistenceException " + e.getMessage());
        }
    
    return clientList;
}
```

However it returns an empty list after producing the following logs.

> 10:15:04,478 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
>
> 10:15:04,478 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
>
> 10:15:04,606 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) SELECT NEW org.domain.carsclass.pojo.ClientView(c.clientId, c.name, c.lastName,c.taxNo, a.mobilePhone, a.town, a.postCode, a.addressLine1, a.clientAddress.companyId, 1 ) FROM Address a INNER JOIN a.client c Company1
>
> PersistenceException org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

I think I'm getting an error in catch block.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Apart from that, you've severe SQL injection attack holes there. Don't forget to work on that too.

Comment: You are swallowing exceptions using a `try...catch` block. This line : `PersistenceException org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection` indicates a severe error which is self-explanatory. You may want to show your database configurations (`persistence.xml` or whatever depending upon your application) with a full exception StackTrace.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers.When i move dialog to new xhtml page it is done i think problem about primefaces dialog.

Comment: @Tiny "This line : PersistenceException org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection indicates a severe error which is self-explanatory." Mmm sorry I may not be the sharpest tool in the shed but to me it is not self-explanatory at all. I am getting this exception on an app after something goes wrong (I think a constraint violation somewhere) and it is not recovering from it. All subsequent queries throw this exception, Any tips on how to debug this?

Comment: @StijndeWitt : Please consider opening a new thread as there is no simple answer. There could be many reasons behind, `PersistenceException org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection`. At least the full exception stack-trace and associated configuration files need to be observed.

Comment: @Tiny Thanks, I did as you said and created [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556244/genericjdbcexception-could-not-open-connection-caused-by-javax-resource-reso) for it.

Comment: For my case replacing `@Transactional` with `@Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)` for DAO method that throw the error solved the issue!