# GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection .. caused by javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000459: Transaction is not active

Tags: java, hibernate

My Hibernate application starts running fine, but at some point something happens (I suspect some unexpected/unhandled constraint violation) that somehow breaks everything. From that point on I keep getting this huge stacktrace that I have trouble reading.... If I restart the app, or logout and login, the problem disappears for a while...

I found [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775774/javax-resource-resourceexception-ij000460-error-checking-for-a-transaction), but was asked in the comments to create a new one for my issue as the exception is a very generic one.

Below a snipped version of the stacktrace. Full stacktrace on pastebin.

```
2015-11-05 17:27:39,349 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-11) UT005023: Exception handling request to /api/ratings/synch: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
        ...
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:163) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        ...
        at net.bridalapp.db.CrudService$$$view1.find(Unknown Source) [classes:]
        ...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        ...
        at net.bridalapp.db.CrudServiceBean.find(CrudServiceBean.java:213) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_65]
        ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:154)
        ...
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:415)
        ...
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000459: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffac1001d4:-67c5b6ff:563b6a43:146d8 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:399)
        ... 348 more
```

http://pastebin.com/DV7zteED

Comment: There are **likely** some misconfigurations in creating a connection pool in JBoss or the piece of database related code being executed is **likely** throwing an exception which causes the current database transaction to be aborted (cancelled) - `Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffac1001d4:-67c5b6ff:563b6a43:146d8 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >`.

Comment: @Tiny Yes I think the DB code throws an exception... But after that it does not get out of it anymore and all queries start to throw this exception. That is what really worries me.... so fragile!

Comment: i am also facing similar issue, did you find any solution to this ?

Comment: @vashishth Actually, no. I am to this day not able to scale up my wildfly instance on Openshift to use two gears because when I do that, after a few hours, this issue starts to rear it's ugly head. If you find a solution, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in wildfly/hibernate. For me the problem was that I was running a long transaction and I had a massive amount of hibernate transactions, that filled up my memory. In my case the answer was, that after a specified number of transactions I did this:
em.flush();
em.clear();
HTH

Comment: For my case replacing `@Transactional` with `@Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)` for DAO method that throw the error solved the issue!